# iterate over nested objects in express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, ejs

I wounder how I can iterate through object in express js. I canget the info from the json file, but as soon as i do a loop it keep saying that its not defined.

What am i missing here, I want it to list them. the though is that I will have a h2 named top 40 and it will list all the object from the Year.top2011.top40.id.top01

any help here.

my index in routing

```
lista = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(lista);

res.render('index', {
  lista: lista
});
```

my index in view

```
<% JSON.parse(lista).forEach(function(item) { %>
 <%- item.Year.top2011.top40.id.top01 %>
<% }; %>
```

my json file

```
{
"Year": {
"top2011": {
  "top40": {
    "id": {
      "top01": {
        "album_cover": "http://o.scdn.co/image/830a22646bc38f72df95ec98e3ab6bb19aa6074b",
        "artist_namn": "Adele",
        "song": "Rolling In The Deep",
        "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/track/7h8Ud480Fm4ReUVxgFF9ZX",
        "youtube": "http://youtu.be/rYEDA3JcQqw"
      },
      "top02": {
        "album_cover": "http://o.scdn.co/image/215c999786e8319a09b7af87a970c2bdb6747c92",
        "artist_namn": "LMFAO",
        "song": "Party Rock Anthem",
        "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/track/1CNJyTUh56oj3OCZOZ5way",
        "youtube": "http://youtu.be/KQ6zr6kCPj8"
      }
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage at the end? have you tried underscore `_.each()`?

Answer (score 0):

`lista` is no longer a JSON string, but a JS object. This line: `JSON.parse(lista).forEach(function(item)` will not work. You need to iterate over `lista` instead: `lista.forEach(function(item) {})`

Comment: It still saying that "lista" its not a function

Answer (score 0):

First of all the structure could be improved:
·Why not store the top40 entries inside an array?
This structure contains the top40_entries, each as an object inside the `top40` *key* **array**

```
{"Year": {
    "2011": {
        "top40": [
            {
            "pos": "top01",
            "album_cover": "http://o.scdn.co/image/830a22646bc38f72df95ec98e3ab6bb19aa6074b",
            "artist_namn": "Adele",
            "song": "Rolling In The Deep",
            "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/track/7h8Ud480Fm4ReUVxgFF9ZX",
            "youtube": "http://youtu.be/rYEDA3JcQqw"
            },
            {
            "pos": "top02",
            "album_cover": "http://o.scdn.co/image/215c999786e8319a09b7af87a970c2bdb6747c92",
            "artist_namn": "LMFAO",
            "song": "Party Rock Anthem",
            "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/track/1CNJyTUh56oj3OCZOZ5way",
            "youtube": "http://youtu.be/KQ6zr6kCPj8"
            }
        ]
    }
}}
```

I would use a `for` loop (when needed) :

```
var top40_2011 = lista.Year.2011.top40; //get the array
for(var i=0; i<top40_2011.length; i++){
    /* Access the values using the keys : */
        //console.log(top40_2011[i].pos);
        //console.log(top40_2011[i].artist_namn);
        //console.log(top40_2011[i].song);
}
```

Note : Remember that arrays start at 0 so top40 would be from [0] to [39];

Comment: Okej, I like the json structure alot(will go with that), but I added the for loop code in my index.js view(I used the express generator). I am having a hard time to get my head around this. In my head the "lista" i a object that I can itterate through, but when I do as I always do with object to itterate them I just wont work. Hairless soon

Comment: @CyrusZei have you tried a console.log() to check in your clients browser? I would use jQuery script that interacts with your view to load the dynamic html content loaded from the JSON